# Identifying websites that use a paywall dynamically

Tags: python, selenium, request

I am interested in identifying websites using paywall, not to bypass to paywall, but use it for research purposes. I use the following code, looks okay for some websites but not for all:

```
import requests

url = "wsj.com" 
response = requests.get(url)

if "pay wall" in response.text.lower() or "paywall" in response.text.lower() or "pay-wall" in response.text.lower():
    print("paywall")
else:
    print("no")
```

How can I capture dynamically loaded paywalls?

Comment: Definition of a "paywall" is vague. You might consider using a curated list instead, such as https://github.com/iamadamdev/bypass-paywalls-chrome/blob/master/src/js/sites.js

Answer (score 1):

Look for the script tag with the type 'application/ld+json'. It's the [Article structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/article#json-ld) designed by Google that many news websites and blogs carry.

There is a specific property called '[isAccessibleForFree](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/paywalled-content)' available to websites that would like to identify themselves as behind a paywall.

Do note that this isn't guaranteed to work everywhere. It depends on the publisher, and whether or not they have these tags on their website.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Article headline</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "image": "https://example.org/thumbnail1.jpg",
      "datePublished": "2025-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
      "dateModified": "2025-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "description": "A most wonderful article",
      "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
      "hasPart":
        {
        "@type": "WebPageElement",
        "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
        "cssSelector" : ".paywall"
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="non-paywall">
      Non-Paywalled Content
    </div>
    <div class="paywall">
      Paywalled Content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```